# Better way to define static method

Tags: c#, generics, static, lambda, extension-methods

I'm facing a requirement to create a static method on my base class,  but don't like that I have to declare type arguments, so I'm wondering if I'm going about this the right way.

Basically, I'm assigning delegates that I'll associate with properties on the class.  I could easily put the method on the inherited classes, like so:

```
public class Foo 
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class InheritsFoo : Foo 
{
    public void AssignDel<TVal>(
        Expression<Func<InheritsFoo, TVal>> expr, 
        Action<InheritsFoo, TVal> action) 
    {
    }
}
```

Or, in an extension class, I could do this:

```
public static void AssignDel<T, TVal>(
    this T source, 
    Expression<T, TVal>> expression, 
    Action<T, TVal> action) 
    where T : Foo 
{
}
```

Both of these would enable me to use `AssignDel` in an instantiated class:

```
var foo = new InheritsFoo();
foo.AssignDel(x => x.Property1, handler);
```

But I have a requirement to make `AssignDel` static. This makes the extension way of doing it useless. It still works in `InheritsFoo`, but I really want to move this to the base class. If I try, the generics argument can't be inferred, and I have to change the usage of the method:

```
InheritsFoo.AssignDel<InheritsFoo, string>(x => x.Property1, handler);
```

Is there a way out here, another way of doing this I haven't thought of?

EDIT: to address the issue in the comments about whether or not the extension method would/should work... I went to the url referenced by @Mark M.  Turns out that if I write it as such...

```
InheritsFoo foo = null;
foo.AssignDel(x => x.Property1, handler);
```

That compiles (don't know if it will run, though).  Still, don't think that qualifies as using a static method, since 'foo' is still considered an instance;  A null instance, but an instance nonetheless.

Comment: Extension methods are already static.  How does a requirement to make the method static get in the way of using extension methods?

Comment: "I have a requirement to make `AssignDel` static". Then make it static.

Comment: @Kirk: Although extension methods are defined as static methods, they can only be used as instance methods of the intended class.

Comment: Why do you care where the method is defined if you're going to make it static. public static methods are global and can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Figuring out a good way to do this requires more knowledge of the usage of these classes and properties than is presented here.  There are higher-level architectural issues that need to be known here before a good answer can be crafted.

Comment: @banging: how am I misinterpreting the first paragraph in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. But you could make your base class generic, `public class Foo<T>`. Then you could write a static method on the base class that depends on the type `T`. Then when you write your derived class, you can make `InheritsFoo` nongeneric and derive from a "constructed type", like this: `public class InheritsFoo : Foo<InheritsFoo>`

Comment: Since the method returns void, I can only assume that it modifies some internal state of the `InheritsFoo` class. If that is true, then how could `AssignDel` be static? Is there some other element to the problem that may shed some light on what `AssignDel` actually does?

Comment: @MarkM: The confusing line i think is "but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type." In order to make what you say true, it should say "but they are ONLY called as ..." ;)

Comment: @Mark M is correct in that extension methods only work on instanced classes.  If anyone thinks they can prove otherwise, please do so.

Comment: Question, do you want that static method defined in base class could modify property in the instance of defining class? You would need to pass the reference of modified class as a parameter.

Comment: TIL [link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html).  It is a little weird since they're called on a null valued-object though.  Thanks banging!

Comment: @Random not exactly true, extension methods just a syntactic sugar of static method, where extended class passed as first parameter. You can call extension method explicitely like System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(str) and will create same code as str.ToList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I needed by just implementing another level in the inheritance chain.

```
public class Foo  
{    
   public string Property1 { get; set; } 
} 

public class Foo<T> : Foo
{
   public static void AssignDel<TVal>(Expression<Func<T, TVal>> expr, Action<T, TVal> action)
   {   }
}

public class InheritsFoo : Foo<InheritsFoo>
{     }
```

I can treat InheritsFoo just as I need it.

Answer (score 1):

> But I have a requirement to make AssignDel static. This makes the
>   extension way of doing it useless. It still works in InheritsFoo, but
>   I really want to move this to the base class. If I try, the generics
>   argument can't be inferred, and I have to change the usage of the
>   method:

This does not make a great deal of sense.

`InheritsFoo.AssignDel` is a static method.

You call said static method by doing `InheritsFoo.AssignDel<InheritsFoo, string>(x => x.Property1, handler);` it seems to meet your requirements.

I don't understand what is wrong with the second option you came up with.  It does what you need to do, it is clear what is happening, is it really because you pass `InheritsFoo` and `string` instead of `foo.AssignDel(x => x.Property1, handler);`?

It seems you could simply do the following and achieve what you want.

```
   public class Foo 
    {
       public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class InheritsFoo : Foo 
    {
        public static void AssignDel<TVal>(
            Expression<Func<InheritsFoo, TVal>> expr, 
            Action<InheritsFoo, TVal> action) 
        {
        }
    }
```

I must be missing something because it would seem that you would use it `InheritsFoo.AssignDel(x => x.Property1, handler);` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Specifying the generics arguments does work, but is more verbose than would be preferred, especially in the case of the TVal type argument.  That's why I'm asking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The extension method already is static.

Supposing you have to not use it in the extension method way, this should work:

```
InheritsFoo.AssignDel(x => x.Property1, handler);
```

In the same way the compiler will infere the type parameters for the extension method form, it will for the old-fashioned static way.

If you need to have the method with two type paremeters, you could create a generic class for this:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Foo {

    public void AssignDel<TVal>( Expression<Func<T, TVal>> expr, Action<T, TVal> action) 
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

In this case, you could do:

```
Foo<InheritFoo>.AssignDel(x => x.PropertyFromInheritFoo, handler);
```

As you can see, you only have to declare one type parameter, the other one is being infered.

Hope it helps

Comment: This will work if I keep the method in InheritsFoo, when I would like to move it to the base Foo class.

Comment: Oh! I got the problem you are facing. It seems you are screw :(

Comment: So... let me check if I understood: You want to have the method in the Foo class and to accept properties for all the hierarchy?

Comment: @ivowiblo... kinda.  The actual code inside the method never needs to evaluate the property, I'm using it as a key to assign the delegate to an internal Dictionary.  The reflection to evaluate the property expression should work fine, even in the base class.